# Remove localized error messages in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I’ve successfully switched dotnet development tools to English, but I’m still getting localized error / warning messages in Visual Studio Code when using C#.
[image: Localized messages]
How can I switch them to English?

Update:

It is DOT.NET 6.

It turned out that this is the fault of the OmniSharp C# extension for VSC, which generates the messages in the pop-up boxes.

I’ve removed (actually renamed) the localization directories in:

c:\Users\userName\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17.debugger\

and

c:\Users\userName\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.17.omnisharp\1.37.17\

I’m afraid, however, that I’ll have to repeat it after every update of the extension.
Does anybody know the way to configure this extension so that it uses English messages?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired to remove language folders (pl) from Microsoft.Net\Framework (64)?

Comment: It’s .NET 6, and after setting the locale to English it works ok. During compilation I get: “The variable 'notUsed' is declared but never used”. So it's VSC fault. Please see my edit for more information.